# Wordpress - Editing a plugin's filter functionality

Tags: php, wordpress, field, hook, membership

I was wondering if someone could help me out.

I have a plugin called Paid Memberships Pro.

On the signup form there are some fields i want to make required.

I have gone through the code and found the place where it sets which fields are required and not required, as below:

```
//require fields
$pmpro_required_billing_fields = array(
    "bfirstname" => $bfirstname,
    "blastname" => $blastname,
    "baddress1" => $baddress1,
    "bcity" => $bcity,
    "bstate" => $bstate,
    "bzipcode" => $bzipcode,
    "bphone" => $bphone,
    "bcountry" => $bcountry,
    "bemail" => $bemail,
    "CardType" => $CardType,
    "AccountNumber" => $AccountNumber,
    "ExpirationMonth" => $ExpirationMonth,
    "ExpirationYear" => $ExpirationYear,
    "CVV" => $CVV
);
$pmpro_required_billing_fields = apply_filters("pmpro_required_billing_fields", $pmpro_required_billing_fields);
$pmpro_required_user_fields = array(
    "username" => $username,
    "password" => $password,
    "password2" => $password2,
    "bemail" => $bemail,
    "bconfirmemail" => $bconfirmemail
);
$pmpro_required_user_fields = apply_filters("pmpro_required_user_fields", $pmpro_required_user_fields);
```

This is found in one of the plugins core files plugins/paid-memberships-pro/preheaders/checkout.php

I want to be able to override this, but i dont want to edit the core files, is there a way i can edit this via my themes functions.php file?

For instance, add the bfirstname and blastname to the $pmpro_required_user_fields?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, ive been searching how to do this but i cant really understand if its possible.

Thanks all :)

Comment: i think you need to override class or function in your theme function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a bit of code that worked perfectly

```
//make sure address fields are required
function my_pmpro_required_user_fields($fields)
{
    global $bfirstname, $blastname, $baddress1, $bcity, $bstate, $bzipcode, $bcountry, $bphone, $bemail;
    $fields["bfirstname"] = $bfirstname;
    $fields["blastname"] = $blastname;
    $fields["baddress1"] = $baddress1;
    $fields["bcity"] = $bcity;
    $fields["bstate"] = $bstate;
    $fields["bzipcode"] = $bzipcode;
    $fields["bphone"] = $bphone;
    $fields["bemail"] = $bemail;
    $fields["bcountry"] = $bcountry;
    return $fields;
}
add_action("pmpro_required_user_fields", "my_pmpro_required_user_fields");

/*
 * Save billing fields when using PayPal
 */
function my_pmpro_paypalexpress_session_vars() {
    $_SESSION['bfirstname'] = $_REQUEST['bfirstname'];
    $_SESSION['blastname'] = $_REQUEST['blastname'];
    $_SESSION['baddress1'] = $_REQUEST['baddress1'];
    $_SESSION['baddress2'] = $_REQUEST['baddress2'];
    $_SESSION['bcity'] = $_REQUEST['bcity'];
    $_SESSION['bstate'] = $_REQUEST['bstate'];
    $_SESSION['bzipcode'] = $_REQUEST['bzipcode'];
    $_SESSION['bphone'] = $_REQUEST['bphone'];
    $_SESSION['bemail'] = $_REQUEST['bemail'];
    $_SESSION['bcountry'] = $_REQUEST['bcountry'];
}
add_action('pmpro_paypalexpress_session_vars', 'my_pmpro_paypalexpress_session_vars');

//load vars back into $_REQUEST
function my_init() {
if(!empty($_REQUEST['review']) && !empty($_REQUEST['token'])) {
    $_REQUEST['bfirstname'] = $_SESSION['bfirstname'];
    $_REQUEST['blastname'] = $_SESSION['blastname'];
    $_REQUEST['baddress1'] = $_SESSION['baddress1'];
    $_REQUEST['baddress2'] = $_SESSION['baddress2'];
    $_REQUEST['bcity'] = $_SESSION['bcity'];
    $_REQUEST['bstate'] = $_SESSION['bstate'];
    $_REQUEST['bzipcode'] = $_SESSION['bzipcode'];
    $_REQUEST['bphone'] = $_SESSION['bphone'];
    $_REQUEST['bemail'] = $_SESSION['bemail'];
    $_REQUEST['bcountry'] = $_SESSION['bcountry'];
}
}
add_action('init', 'my_init');
```

Answer (score 1):

*(Put this code in your chid theme function.php file)*

Not shure, but you can try to use `remove_filters` first:

```
remove_filters("pmpro_required_billing_fields", $pmpro_required_billing_fields);
remove_filters("pmpro_required_billing_fields", $pmpro_required_user_fields);
```

Then you can clone those arrays, customizing them (and changing their names a little bit), and then re-apply the filter back for that customized arrays:

```
$pmpro_required_billing_fields2 = array(
    /* your custom code goes here */
);
$pmpro_required_billing_fields2 = apply_filters("pmpro_required_billing_fields", $pmpro_required_billing_fields2);

$pmpro_required_user_fields2 = array(
    /* your custom code goes here */
);
$pmpro_required_user_fields2 = apply_filters("pmpro_required_user_fields", $pmpro_required_user_fields2);
```

It's just an untested idea, hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

If somebody still needs this - In this case, best practice would be to use `pmpro_required_user_fields` or `pmpro_required_billing_fields` filters, depending on which fields you want to make required - user or billing fields.

So, for example, if you need a billing phone (`bphone`) field to be required, this would do the job:

```
add_filter( "pmpro_required_billing_fields", 'yourtheme_require_phone' );
function yourtheme_require_phone($pmpro_required_user_fields) {

  global $bphone;

  $pmpro_required_user_fields["bphone"] = $bphone;

  return $pmpro_required_user_fields;
}
```